# Significado de Acabar de + <infinitivo>

Tags: verbos

A seguinte frase parece-me difícil de aceitar:

> (1) Ela acabou de ensinar.

Onde ensinar tem o [sentido 2. do Aulete Digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/ensinar): "Dar aulas (de); LECIONAR"

Pode, contudo, dizer-se:

> (2) Ela acabou de ensinar frações ao 5º ano.
>   (3) Ela acabou de lecionar uma aula/várias aulas (mas não simplesmente "lecionar").

Onde "ensinar" tem o sentido 3.: "Fazer adquirir ou adotar, por ensinamento ou por experiência". Também se pode dizer, com "ensinar" no sentido 2.:

> (4) Ela acabou de deixar de ensinar.

O Aulete define também ["acabar de + <infinitivo>"](http://www.aulete.com.br/acabar):

> b) seguido da prep. *de* + v. principal no infinit., indicando término de uma ação: *"...jamais havia pensado no que ela acabara de perguntar."* (Paulo Coelho, Brida); *"...ao lado da motocicleta que acabava de ganhar."* (Antonio Callado, Bar Don Juan).]

Ora esta explicação parece-me claramente insuficiente. Poderia dizer-se o exatamente o mesmo de "deixar de + <infinitivo>", mas o significado dessoutra locução é claramente distinto (ainda que implique cessação).

Então, qual é o significado de "acabar de + "?
E porque é que "Ela acabou de ensinar." não é uma frase possível?

Comment: E a pergunta é?

Comment: @Jacinto A pergunta é qual é o significado de "acabar de + <infinitivo>" e porque "ela acabou de ensinar" não é possível, já que seria (discutivelmente) compatível com o significado apontado no Aulete ("término de uma ação").

Comment: Fixe, vou pensar no assunto. Não se perdia clarificares isso no fim da pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa apresenta dois significados muito parecidos de **acabar de + infinitivo**:

> **13** Ir até ao fim, terminar (a ação expressa pelo verbo no infinitivo). ≠ começar a. *Acabou de ver o filme da televisão e foi-se deitar.*
>   **14** Ter feito ou ter acontecido em momento imediatamente anterior ou muito recente (a ação ou processo expresso pelo verbo no infinitivo). *Acabei de mandar um telex. O avião acabou de aterrar*.

O ponto **13** significa *concluir*. De facto o Aulete está confuso. Interpreta *término* como *conclusão*, parece significar **13**, mas os exemplos são de **14**.

Recorrendo só à experiência pessoal, eu diria que *acabar de*, no sentido 13, só se aplica a processos com princípio e fim possíveis de definir *a priori*. Caso contrário não seria possível falar de conclusão.

> Acabei finalmente de ler o *Guerra e Paz*. (Os limites à priori são a primeira e última página.)
>   Estou a acabar de fazer o jantar. (O arroz está quase no ponto.)
>   Acabei de ensinar as frações ao 5º ano. (Havia uma tarefa programada, que foi concluída.)
>   Acabei de construir a casa. (Coloquei a última telha, ou seja lá qual for a última coisa que se faz.)

No sentido 14, *acabar de*, novamente recorrendo apenas à experiência pessoal, aplica-se só a eventos vistos como unidades claramente limitadas num espaço curto de tempo (aterrar o avião, mandar um telex); não se aplica a verbos quando designam faculdades ou atividades recorrentes ou continuadas ao longo da vida. Por isso:

> (1a) *Acabei de falar com ele* mas não (1b) *acabei de falar*.
>   (2a) *Acabei mesmo de pensar nisso* mas não (2b) *acabei de pensar*.
>   (3a) *Acabei de lecionar uma aula* mas não (3b) *acabei de lecionar*.
>   (4a) *Acabei de pescar um chicharro* mas não (4b) *acabei de pescar*.
>   (5a) *Acabei de fazer 40 anos de ensino*, (5b) não *acabei de ensinar.*
>   (6a) *Acabei de ensinar Inglês; agora vai ser Francês.* mas não (6b) *Acabei de ensinar Inglês.*

*Inglês* em (6a) seria entendido como uma ou várias lições de Inglês nesse dia. Uma razão para não se dizer as alternativas (b) é que elas seriam ambíguas: não se perceberia se a pessoa tinha parado temporariamente ou definitivamente de falar, pensar, etc.

A tua frase (4), *ela acabou de deixar de ensinar* parece-me possível gramaticalmente, interpretando-a como *acabou de dar a sua derradeira aula, acabou de se despedir do ensino, acabou de se reformar, acabou de largar o ensino.* Agora o estilo é péssimo.

Comment: Ah, nem me ocorrera o significado 13 do dicionário da Verbo. Repara que os exemplos do Aulete são ambos com o significado 14. Agora, o argumento de que as frases (b) são impermissíveis devido a ambiguidade é que me parece fraco, pelo menos precisaria de mais qualquer coisa. Afinal de contas, "acabei de ler o Guerra e Paz/de fazer o jantar/de ensinar frações" são  ambíguas entre 13 e 14. Ler "Acabei de lecionar uma aula" como 13 parece-me muito díficil e "Acabei de fazer 40 anos de docência/ensinar Inglês" só me é possível ler como 14.

Comment: Também não sei se a limitação que dás ao uso de 14 é correta (unidades claramente delimitada no tempo).  "Acabei de ensinar" não é possível, mas também não o é "Acabei de ensinar durante 40 anos". Por outro lado, "acabei de fazer 40 anos de ensino" já funciona, onde o evento já é o completar dos 40 anos, não o ensinar.

Comment: Eu não digo que as (b) são impermissíveis; apenas que não as ouço: é uma mera constatação. Existir ambiguidade entre 13 e 14 não é importante: implicam ambas uma 'tarefa' ou acontecimento concluído; não que se tenha parado para todo o sempre de fazer isto ou aquilo. Ambiguidade entre 13 e 14 existe no jantar, aula, frações, inglês. O 14 significa que aconteceu mesmo agora: não consegues ter lido o *Guerra e Paz* todo mesmo agora, para não falar dos 40 anos.

Comment: @Artefacto Precisei o meu entendimento do uso do 14

Comment: OK, o meu 2o comentário não faz muito sentido. "Acabei de ensinar (durante 40 anos)" não funciona porque não encaixa na definição 14 "acontecer recentemente"; quando li essa parte esqueci-me do resto. Para acontecer (como um todo) recentemente, tem de acontecer num espaço de tempo curto, como dizes. Acho que é isso, não (ou não somente) a ambiguidade que apontas a seguir.

Comment: Mas insisto que os exemplos que dás para 13 são problemáticos. "Acabei de ler o Guerra e Paz": ambígua entre "já acabei de ler o Guerra e Paz (há seis semanas)" (13) e "acabei (agora mesmo) de ler o Guerra e Paz" (14). E o exemplo dos 40 anos tem o significado 14, não 13, porque o evento é o completar dos 40 anos, não lecionar. E "acabei de lecionar uma aula" é difícil ler como 13, "já acabei de lecionar uma aula" (só se fosse um professor novo), por isso deve ser 14 "acabei agora mesmo". Por outro lado, "acabei de lecionar *a* aula" já se poderia ler como 13 (14 também seria possível).

Comment: Acabei de mudar a aula e Inglês para o 14. De facto, se quisesse dizer o 13, diria "acabei agora a aula", não "acabei de dar a aula". Eu escolhi o *Guerra e Paz* exatamente por aquilo ser grande como o caraças e eu não consigo imaginar ninguém ler aquilo tudo num espaço curto de tempo (repara nos exemplos da Verbo ou do Aulete, aterrar avião, ganhar motocicleta, etc.). De facto *fazer 40 anos* é mais facilmente interpretado como o momento em que se faz 40 anos.

Answer (score 2):

Em **ptBR**, ensinar como verbo intransitivo, seu exemplo nº 1 ("Ela acabou de ensinar"), é usado quando o contexto não deixa dúvida em relação ao que foi ensinado.

(a) - "Será que alguém vai saber resolver essa equação?"

(b) - "João, a professora acabou de ensinar."

"Ela acabou de ensinar" sem contexto, não é usado em ptBR.

Os exemplos 2 e 3 não apresentam problemas, ensinar está sendo usado como verbo transitivo.  Pode ser transitivo direto ou indireto.

td - "Ela ensina matemática naquela escola."

ti - "Meu pai ensinou meu irmão a nadar."

O exemplo 4 ("Ela acabou de deixar de ensinar") não seria ouvido por estas bandas. Simplesmente diríamos:

"Ela acabou de largar o magistério." ou

"Ela acabou de deixar o  magistério."

Finalmente, "acabar de" indica que uma ação foi completada há pouco tempo. Corresponde ao "I've just...." (I've just seen, written, told, etc)

Comment: Concordo que corresponde a "I've just <past participle>", mas isso só ajuda quem conhecer a expressão em inglês. O significado implica a ação tem sido completada há pouco tempo. Contudo, se eu tiver tido uma carreira no ensino, mas a tiver deixado há pouco pouco, não posso dizer "Acabei de ensinar". Porquê?

Answer (score 0):

"Acabar de" pode significar que a acção foi praticada há pouco tempo atrás. equivalendo a HAVE JUST.

Nunca se pode dizer, por exemplo: "ele acabou de chegar". Porque o CHEGAR não é um processo, diz-se ele ACABA DE CHEGAR, isto é o verbo está no presente mas a representar algo que aconteceu num passado muito recente.

Comment: Se, como tu dizes, para exprimir uma ação acabada de realizar o verbo *acabar* tem que estar no presente, os exemplos do Dicionário da Academia de Ciências de Lisboa estão errados (ênfase minha): **Acabar de** 14 Ter feito ou ter acontecido em momento imediatamente anterior ou muito recente (a ação ou processo expresso pelo verbo no infinitivo). **Acabei** de mandar um telex. O avião **acabou** de aterrar.